# Publish API to the organisation to subscribe in WSO2 API1.7

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have published an application as api in wso2 api manager. This is now required to be subscribed by the entire organization. Do I need to create users and roles for all the employees to access the wso2 store to subscribe the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to create users and roles for all the employees to access
>   the wso2 store to subscribe the API?

Yes, You can't invoke the APIs without subscription. Creating individual users is depends on you. You can share the access-token amoung your employees to access the API.

A user should have `Login` and `Subscribe` permission to subscribe and invoke the API.

[image]

Have a look on [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+User+Roles) to know how to create new roles with permissions

Comment: Could Access tokens be generated for as long as the API needs to be used.For example my API has to be used on a daily purpose for the whole year and continued.So I can create the validity of the access token to be alive for so long time and renew the token only after the proper expiry.Because in my case its an organization wide API so I would not be able to convey the access token so easily.

Comment: You can specify the expiration time of the access token when generating it.